# Reading/writing to an obj. repr. of an object with static storage duration and declared type

Tags: c, char, posix, language-lawyer

Consider an example where we have a `static` file-scope `struct` object declaration and two function that are serializing/deserializing its object representation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct test {
    int a;
    int b;
};

static struct test tst;

void test_set(struct test value){
    tst = value;
}

void test_serialize(const char *path){
    int fd = open(path, O_WRONLY);
    if(fd != -1){
        ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd, &tst, sizeof tst);
        if(bytes_written == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while writing data.\n");
        }
        close(fd);
    }
}

void test_desirialize(const char *path){
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd != -1){
        ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, &tst, sizeof tst);
        if(bytes_read == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read data.\n");
        }
        close(fd);
    }
}

int main(void){
    struct test t1 = {1, 2};
    test_set(t1);
    test_serialize("/tmp/test");
    test_desirialize("/tmp/test");
    printf("tst.a = %d, tst.b = %d\n", tst.a, tst.b);
}
```

In the example we can see an assignment of some value to `static struct test tst` and then serializing/de-serializing it. I have questions about conformance of the code.

Looking up through the standard I found the paragraph `7.24.1(p3)` that provides a clarification for copying functions:

> For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be
>   interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every
>   possible object representation is valid and has a different value).

So if the same is assumed for `read`/`write` functions and applying rules from `6.5` that

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types:
>
> [...]
>
> — a character type.

We can state that it is conforming to do such serializing/deserializing. But man-pages for [read.2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [write.2](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) does not specify anything like that.

Is it possible to make an assumption that buffer meantioned in `read`/`write` man pages treats its characters as `unsigned char` either?

Comment: `read()` and `write()` are Posix interfaces, not part of the standard C library. But the documentation you refer to is not even from Posix; it's a Linux manpage. (Although Posix does not provide any further details about this issue, it would be a better citation in a [language-lawyer] question.) In any event, Posix does not permit integer representations other than 2's complement, so the signedness of `char` is not relevant in a Posix implementation; no `char` type has a trap representation.

Comment: @rici I don't really get the point that you mentioned that _no `char` type has a trap representation_. That's true, but how does that help? I thought the reason for using `unsigned char` was that object representation is defined as `unsigned char[sizeof tst]` so  it is well-defined to pass any pointer to any object type.

Comment: you quote a paragraph which notes that every value for an unsigned char is unique and valid. Posix effectively extends that to all char types, so it's just as well-defined to use a `char` as an `unsigned char` in a Posix environment. I think it's reasonable to assume that read() and write() operates on characters.

Comment: In your code, neither `test_serialize` or `test_desirialize` reads or writes anything unless `/tmp/test` already exists -- it will not be created without `O_CREAT` specified.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sure, but I manually created the file before.